# How to log JSON responses in Dropwizard (Jersey)

Tags: java, http, jersey, dropwizard

I would like to know how one would configure Dropwizard to log the JSON response.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In dropwizard 0.8.1 (also tried in 0.9.0-SNAPSHOT), add to `Application.run(...)`:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
...
public void run(MyApplicationConfiguration conf, Environment env) throws Exception {
    // do your stuff and then add LoggingFilter
    env.jersey().register(new LoggingFilter(
                     Logger.getLogger(LoggingFilter.class.getName()),
                     true)
                 );
}
```

To configure logger, add in your configuration file (e.g.:`conf.yml`):

```
logging:
  loggers:
    org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter: INFO
```

Comment: LoggingFilter  is deprecated. Please update the answer with LoggingFeatuers

Answer (score 13):

In the Service subclass (ex HelloWorldService), in the run method, add:

```
environment.setJerseyProperty(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS, LoggingFilter.class.getName());
environment.setJerseyProperty(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS, LoggingFilter.class.getName());
```

and then make sure that com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter (or any parent package) is configured at least at log level INFO, for example:

```
logging:
  loggers:
    "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter": INFO
```

Comment: For some reason the logger doesn't seem to configure the level?

Comment: Note that this was in the Dropwizard 0.6.x days. In 0.7.0 it might have changed. I never built anything with Dropwizard 0.7.0, and have moved away from it, so I'm not sure. Sorry.

Comment: LoggingFilter internally calls logger.info(...)
Here is the snippet:
    private void log(final StringBuilder b) {
        if (logger != null) {
            logger.info(b.toString());
        }
    }

Answer (score 9):

The answers are a bit outdated, this is how it needs to be done in newer versions:

```
env.jersey().register(new LoggingFeature(logger, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY));
```

Where `logger` is a `java.util.logging.Logger`

Answer (score 6):

In dropwizard 0.7.0 the correct syntax to enable request and response logging is:

```
environment.jersey().property(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS, LoggingFilter.class.getName());
environment.jersey().property(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS, LoggingFilter.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 3):

Logging Filter is **deprecated**, so we should be using **LoggingFeature**.

Unfortunately I could not get it working with @Click Upvote's answer of

`env.jersey().register(new LoggingFeature(logger, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY));`

Following Code worked for me. They correspond to different constructors.

```
    environment.jersey().register(new LoggingFeature(Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME), Level.INFO, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY, LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE));
```

Here are the constructors in both the cases.

```
public LoggingFeature(Logger logger, Integer maxEntitySize) {
    this(logger, (Level)null, DEFAULT_VERBOSITY, maxEntitySize);
}

public LoggingFeature(Logger logger, Level level, LoggingFeature.Verbosity verbosity, Integer maxEntitySize) {
    this.filterLogger = logger;
    this.level = level;
    this.verbosity = verbosity;
    this.maxEntitySize = maxEntitySize;
}
```

Setting the level is doing the trick.