# Dropwizard Jersey logging request/response as ERROR, but why?

Tags: jersey, dropwizard, java.util.logging

I have added this line

```
environment.jersey().register(new LoggingFeature(Logger
    .getLogger(LoggingFeature.class.getName()), Level.OFF, 
          LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT, null));
```

in my `run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment)` method looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171273/how-to-print-server-responses-using-loggingfeature-in-dropwizard-1-0-2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213568/how-to-log-json-responses-in-dropwizard-jersey)

I am only getting stuff in the logs if the `Level` is set to `OFF` and all my requests/response messages are logged as ERROR, but why ERROR?

Here is an example of the log:

```
ERROR  [11:17:41.603] [dw-31 - GET /helloworld] o.g.j.l.LoggingFeature -  1 

* Server has received a request on thread dw-31 - GET /helloworld
1 > GET http://localhost:8080/helloworld
1 > Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
1 > Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
1 > Cache-Control: max-age=0
1 > Connection: keep-alive
1 > Cookie: openid_provider=openid; _ga=GA1.1.1009619719.1483436711
1 > Host: localhost:8080
1 > Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
1 > User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36

ERROR  [11:17:41.615] [dw-31 - GET /helloworld] o.g.j.l.LoggingFeature -  1 * Server responded with a response on thread dw-31 - GET /helloworld
1 < 200
```

My Resource class:

```
@Path("/helloworld")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloWorldResource {

    public HelloWorldResource() { }

    @GET
    public Response helloWorld(){
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        return Response.ok().build();

    }
}
```

My main application class:

```
public class ApiApplication extends Application<ApiConfiguration>{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    new ApiApplication().run(args);
}

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<ApiConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    // nothing to do yet
}

@Override
public void run(ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration, Environment environment) throws Exception {

    final TemplateHealthCheck healthCheck =
            new TemplateHealthCheck(apiConfiguration.getTemplate());
    environment.healthChecks().register("template", healthCheck);

    final HelloWorldResource helloWorldResource = new HelloWorldResource();
    final JerseyEnvironment jerseyEnvironment = environment.jersey();
    jerseyEnvironment.register(helloWorldResource);

    jerseyEnvironment.register(new LoggingFeature(Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME), Level.OFF, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY, Integer.MAX_VALUE));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall try changing the `LoggingFeature` to  -

```
environment.jersey().register(new LoggingFeature(
      Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.class.getName()), Level.FINE,
             LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT, null));
```

Since the current logging is set to `Level.OFF`. The application does not try to log anything and returns from the [filter implementation of `ContainerRequestFilter`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/ServerLoggingFilter.java#L94) and [filter implementation of `ContainerResponseFilter`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/ServerLoggingFilter.java#L115) interfaces with the [`java.util.Logger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) within which the [`log(LogRecord)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) method is overriden by some subclass of `Logger` which is modifying the level to ERROR.

I would second the thought of this implementation to be considered as poor. Expecting at the same time that changing to `Level.OFF` shouldn't log anything at all. (at least not under `ERROR`)

At the same time the verbosity specified is [`LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.Verbosity.html#PAYLOAD_TEXT) so the entire

> Content of HTTP headers as well as entity content of textual media
>   types is logged.

which is the details after your [ERROR] message in the logs.

Comment: Thanks it helped, well I could'nt either get my head around it that logs were produced when set to `OFF` but nothing was produced when set to `ALL`. It did not occur to me to try out `FINE`. Just trying to figure out how to log when a specific request is called from a given  user. But thanks a lot for the explanation @nullpointer

Comment: @TheLearner I am not very sure where this belongs to at present. But this should be raised as unexpected behaviour(bug) to either of the libraries involved.

Comment: I will report it asap